# Windows Server Backup snap-in module is never installed

Tags: windows-server-backup, windows-server-2012

When installing Windows Server Backup the install finish and I receive no error messages.
But Windows Server Backup snap-in module is never installed!

The link to Windows Server Backup is also not visible on Administrative Tools.

Normally wbadmin.msc is installed in "windows\system32\wbadmin.msc" but the wbadmin.msc is never installed in this folder.

I have tried to uninstalled the service multiple times and install it again but it does not matter, the snap-in module never installs.

What can I do?

Comment: Check your logs and find out why?

Comment: Well, where do I find the install log files when adding a new "feature" to windows? Do I need to activate logging and if I do, how do I do that?

Comment: *sigh*  Look through the Event Logs.  Sort by time if you know when you tried to install it and go to that time, or check for events from source `msi installer`.

Comment: Nothing is reported in the event logs. The installation finished without any error at all.

Comment: I solved this problem by installing another feature (I used the Network Load Balancing feature) together with Windows Server Backup feature. Don't ask me why this worked, but it did. But then uninstalling the Network Load Balancing feature also uninstalls Windows Server Backup. Who knows why? (Can't answer my own question right now because I have less than 10 reputations)

Comment: Same problem, Server Backup dissapeared after removing DFS namespaces and replication. Reappeared after reinstalling DFS namespaces and replication. Well, maybe it feels to be lonely not having a role installed. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing the Network Load Balancing feature together with Windows Server Backup feature.

Comment: This worked for me too. Bonkers.

Comment: Thank you for this...it was driving me nuts...especially since I had been running backups for weeks as a scheduled task just fine, so I knew I had set it up at some point!